# how to create 400 bad request so that I can verify a feature

Tags: http

currently I am doing a work to handle the 400 bad request status error. I am wondering how to create a request that server will return 400 status.

Comment: Create a page on your server that will send 400 header?

Comment: what server do you use?

Comment: Simply go to your server webpage that does not exist. It will show 404 as the response code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A HTTP 400 error occurs due to bad syntax in the request.

To create a request that forces the server to return a 400 error, you can:

1. Open a TCP connection to port 80 on your server
2. Send junk
3. Observe response.

Comment: Thanks. The server is a web application. Can you tell me how to send junk?

Comment: You can hard code yourself mashing the keyboard. Or random number generator converted to text. The whole point is to send something the server will be unable to understand because it is not a proper HTTP request.

Comment: I have found another way to send a bad request. If a url nead a get action, but we send a post action to it, we will get 400 status. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

I found an easy way to generate 400 Bad Request Error:

Appending `/%` at the end of the URL should work for most websites.

For example:

```
http://abc.go.com/%
http://www.checkupdown.com/%
https://www.oath.com/%
https://www.apple.com/%
```

The above URLs generate the following page:

[image]

Note that this method doesn't guarantee to work for ALL websites on the internet.

Since the server can decide what to do when seeing `/%`.

=========================== explanation ===========================

The percent sign (`%`) is a character used for encoding special characters in URLs. When `%` is included in a URL, it is interpreted as a symbol for URL encoding.

In my cases, `%` is not followed by any characters that need to be URL-encoded. So the above URLs are not valid URLs, and the server returns a 400 Bad Request error to indicate that the request cannot be understood.

Comment: 2022: Firefox strips `%` in many cases now before making the request, but doing it as`/%foo`  goes through.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/)
2. Enter your servers url you want to test
3. Before sending the request, make postman send anything else then the request type your server expects. For example if your server expects a GET request, just send him a POST request.
4. BOOOOM - surprise! Your server should throw some 400er, actually 405, error.